# Merging two tables with low quality data

Tags: excel, merge, powerquery

I've been spinning my wheels on this one for a while and have had trouble finding a relatively pertinent answer elsewhere. This seems to me to be pretty convoluted and maybe not even possible, so if that's the case please let me know and I can find other workarounds. And if it would be easier to just refer me to reading materials, etc. please feel free as well.

My goal is to merge two tables together via Power Query in Excel, where one of the tables has typos and empty fields where there shouldn't be. I've attached a picture here for reference: [image: Table 1]
The second table is a "master table" of sorts, that the first table should cross-reference against. The desired process/result is attached here: [image: Desired Result]

To get the names to match, I've been trying to fine-tune fuzzy match's similarity figure, though I'm not quite there yet as some of the typos are too different. It seems to me that the real difficult part is trying to reconcile the cities based on the correct customer name.

Maybe there is a better way to do this outside of Power Query, but that's just where I started as it made the most sense to me. Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are all Source Customers called "Customer" and their customer number? If so, you can start by only looking at the number and not the whole line. >>> Next, import a list of American cities, and use conditional formatting to find any misspelled. At that point it should reconcile fine.

Comment: @CameronCritchlow Unfortunately there are no customer numbers, just the name. Though the list of cities is a really good idea, thanks!

Comment: Do you have customers (regardless of spelling) on you input list that don't exist on your master list?

Comment: @CameronCritchlow (do I need to ping when replying? Sorry if that's unnecessary). I do have a handful of customers not on the master list. Right now I'm dealing with that by making them into a 'transformation table' as part of a fuzzy match in PQ.

Comment: Hm, Sounds like a lot of manual work either way...

Comment: Power Query uses the Jaccard similarity algorithm to measure the similarity between pairs of instances. Given your examples, `Company 2` will be a better match for `Company 1` than will `Company 1, Inc`.  If your real data is this similar to what you provide for an example, I don't believe fuzzy matching by itself will work.

Comment: I think you're both right. I don't know that there's a reasonable solution without improving the quality of the data first. I appreciate the help! Back to the drawing board. I'm good for the question to be closed, please & thanks.